# I need to design a data structure that searches, deletes, inserts and compute sum of elements within a range efficiently

Tags: data-structures

Implement a data structure that stores a set  of integers with the following allowed operations:
∙ add() — add integer  into the set  (if it was there already, the set doesn’t change).
∙ del() — remove integer  from the set  (if there was no such element, nothing happens).
∙ find() — check whether  is in the set  or not.
∙ sum(, ) — output the sum of all elements  in  such that  ≤  ≤ .

Comment: Hash-table is a natural representation of a set. All the operations, but summation, are amortised O(1) and summation is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

You can go with [AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) where each operation will cost O(lgn). In each node **u** you will store the sum of all elements in the subtree rooted at **u**. The hardest part is the delete operation, but there are lot of implementations out there. If the numbers are small enough, then you can try [fenwick tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) to answer all your questions with minimum code effort.